# Format Phone Number in PHP

Tags: php

I have a phone number that is stored in a database like:

5555555555

I want to format this like:

(555) 555-5555

using php i have the following code:

```
<?php
  $data = $order['contactphone'];

  if(  preg_match( '/^\+\d(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})$/', $data,  $matches ) )
      {
        $result = $matches[1] . '-' .$matches[2] . '-' . $matches[3];
        echo $result;
      }
?>
```

This returns nothing at all once so ever. Not even an error. How can I do this?

Comment: Just a thought, but is your site limited to users in the United States? International numbers don't all follow the same pattern.

Comment: Have you considered approaching this problem using something besides a regular expression?

Comment: Why the `\+\d` in the beginning of your regex?

Comment: It's "whatsoever" no "once so ever" ;)

Comment: If you allow an optional `+1` at the beginning, the beginning of the regexp should be `(:?\+\d)?`. Your regexp makes this required, that's why it doesn't match that phone number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I've used in the past. Not as elegant as a regex I suppose but it can get the job done:

```
/**
 * Formats a phone number
 * @param string $phone
 */
static public function formatPhoneNum($phone){
  $phone = preg_replace("/[^0-9]*/",'',$phone);
  if(strlen($phone) != 10) return(false);
  $sArea = substr($phone,0,3);
  $sPrefix = substr($phone,3,3);
  $sNumber = substr($phone,6,4);
  $phone = "(".$sArea.") ".$sPrefix."-".$sNumber;
  return($phone);
}
```

p.s. I didn't write this, just something I grabbed six years ago.

Answer (score 1):

Change regex from `'/^\+\d(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})$/'` to `'/^(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})$/'`, i.e.:

```
if(  preg_match( '/^(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})$/', $data,  $matches ) )
      {
        $result = '(' . $matches[1] . ') ' .$matches[2] . '-' . $matches[3];
        echo $result;
      }
```