# HTML/PHP Table Formatting

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm very new to both HTML and PHP and I'm trying to get my table formatting right. I'm importing information from a database and it's all coming through correctly.

This is my code for my table

```
    echo "
    <tr>
    <td>".$row["id"]."</td>
    <td><center>".$row["firstname"]." ".$row["lastname"]."</center></td>
    <td><center>".$row["addr1"]."<br>".$row["addr2"]."<br>".$row["city"].",".$row["state"]." ".$row["zip"]."</center></td>
    <td>".$row["phone"]."</td>
    </tr>";
```

In my database, if a phone number was not entered it's saved as 0. Otherwise the number is saved as `5556667777`. How can I format output in HTML so that my phone number is `(555)-666-7777`.

Also, the way I coded the address it should show up as

```
<br>
<br>567 Main Street
<br>Apt 4
<br>New York, New York 88888
```

but if there's no information in the addr 2 (i.e. Apt 4) there's a blank space.
Can I put a conditional inside html to remove this?

Comment: Why aren't you doing this with PHP?

Comment: The file itself is a php file but the table is html I think. I know I'm using both. The table code above is within my php portion of the file

Comment: try keep it to one question per post - for the phone number : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21565164/format-phone-number-in-php to detect empty value `empty()`

Comment: `if(!empty($row....)){...} else {...}`

Comment: how is the address showing up?

Comment: Don't forget that PHP and HTML are two different things, and in many cases PHP could care less if you're writing HTML, PDF or a text file.

Comment: @Dagon My question isn't the same as the one you linked me to. I'm trying to figure out how to do this inside my table formatting and how to plan for a potential '0' instead fo 10 digits

Comment: yes it really is ;) table is irrelevent

Comment: and yet the context is totally different and doesn't cover what I'm asking.

Comment: If you are interested in formatting, CSS should be the tool of choice. Of course this is directly related to the HTML, but should be disjoint from the PHP logic (investigate the idea of Model View Controller). Here is a good [link for table formatting](http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/table-formatting/)

Comment: you admit your new, just try the function in the link i gave you. add a check for 0 in it as well

Answer (score 0):

The `<style>...` should be placed in your css file.

```
   echo "<style>td {text-align:center;}</style>
    <tr>
    <td>".$row["id"]."</td>
    <td>".$row["firstname"]." ".$row["lastname"]."</td>
    <td>".$row["addr1"]."<br>".(!empty($row["addr2"])?($row["addr2"]."<br>"):''.$row["city"].",".$row["state"]." ".$row["zip"]."</td>
    <td>(".substr($row["phone"],0,3).") ".substr($row["phone"],3,3)."-".substr($row["phone"],6,4)."</td>
    </tr>";
```